# Apache Ant Build, jar with external librarys

Tags: ant, build, jar

i have a Apache Ant build.xml to create a simple executeable jar file, but this file is very big.
Now i have the idea to build a executeable jar file with my code and have a directory named "lib" with all external jar files.
I think this will reduce the size of my application to 3%.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what's the question? An Ant build file to compile and build an executable jar can (should) be very small, no need for a lot of complications.

Comment: Checkout the manifestclasspath task. This is useful to generate the classpath entry in the jar manifest.